# How to configure Webpack CSS hot reload with static <link> tag?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to configure **Webpack v5** and **webpack-dev-server v4.0.0-beta.3** and have trouble enabling **CSS hot reload** for static `<link>` tags inside static HTML. I'm using API to start Webpack and its dev server.

Repository with full test case: https://github.com/tgrajewski/webpack_css_reload

Excerpt from the above repository with the Webpack configuration:

```js
compiler = webpack({
    'mode': 'development',
    'entry': './main.js',
    'devtool': false,
    'output': {
        'filename': 'out.js',
        'path': path.join(process.cwd(), 'build'),
        'publicPath': '/'
    },
    'module': {
        'rules': [
            {
                'test': /\.css$/,
                'use': ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            }
        ]
    },
    'stats': 'none',
    'infrastructureLogging': {
        'level': 'info'
    }
});

server = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
    'port': 8080,
    'devMiddleware': {
        'writeToDisk': true
    },
    'client': {
        'logging': 'info'
    },
    'static': [
        {
            'directory': 'build',
            'watch': true
        }
    ]
});
```

I get full page reload when modifying the `main.css` file. Anyone knows how to enable CSS hot reload using only the static `<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">` tag inside `index.html`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable HMR for any file, this file must be part of the webpack build (so it will watch it).

In your case, `css` file is not of this build, since the `html` file loads it.

In order to fix this, you can add an import to the css file from the `main.js` file, this will add it to the dependency tree of your build.

BTW, it is recommended to use [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) in order to generate the html file.

I've made a PR to your demo, which implements all of above.
https://github.com/tgrajewski/webpack_css_reload/pulls

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time! I've installed `webpack-dev-server` with NPM and the arguments are not in the order from the linked master branch code. And also according to this release https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/releases/tag/v4.0.0-beta.0 the `hot` option is enabled by default (enabling `hot` manually doesn't seem to change anything). But maybe I've misunderstood something.

Comment: Can you share a small repo with the issue?

Comment: Yes, I've linked small test repository in the question.

Comment: Ha, I've missed it, your HMR doesn't works because u are changing a file which is not part of the webpack's tree.
Your build folder should be generated automatically, I will prepare a PR

Comment: I've looked into the PR you've made, now it makes more sense to me how Webpack works, thank you! I was hoping that a static `<link>` tag and static HTML file would suffice, are you sure it isn't possible?

Comment: And what about the MiniCssExtractPlugin? Its documentation mentions something about preloaded CSS and `<link>` tags, but I had no luck with configuring it. https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#using-preloaded-or-inlined-css